# PHP include format for Kirtan Central website

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to use a PHP include for the first time. I'm reasonably familiar with HTML, and new to PHP.

I've put the HTML for my header in a separate PHP file, and am trying to call it from `http://www.kirtancentral.com/index-test.html`. You can see I attempted it in a bunch of formats, I was of course hoping this one would do the trick:

```
<?php include("/home/danielctucker/kirtancentral.com/includes/header.php"); ?>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You have to make your web server execute the PHP before any PHP embedded in a page will work. The fact you can see the PHP when you View Source shows that this is not happening.

Most servers (which have PHP installed and enabled) will only look in files with a `.php` file extension for PHP code (although this can be configured otherwise).

Try changing from `index.html` to `index.php`. If that doesn't work, then you need to install and enable PHP (if you control the server) or change your hosting pacakage.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have PHP enabled on your server.

Install/enable PHP

Answer (score 0):

Also it is good practice to use a relative path to your PHP script:

```
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>
```

Of course, this will only work when you have PHP enabled on your server.

Radhe-Shyam! :)